# How to get sum of custom attributes in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, sharepoint

I am trying to retrieve the value of the custom attribute "mrbvalue". The html is what sharepoint gives me after I enter the data in the database. So I can't add my own classes or change anything. The console.log() is just me seeing if it works. The code works but when I click the radio button's "No" & "Sometimes" the console prints the "Yes" value.

```
<tr>
                <td> <span>P1</span> </td>
                <td> <div class="n-mrb n-choice tbl" nfield="td_p1" value="1">

        <div class="mrb-item"><label><input type="radio" name="td_p1"  mrbvalue="Yes"> Yes</label></div>

        <div class="mrb-item"><label><input type="radio" name="td_p1"  mrbvalue="No"> No</label></div>

        <div class="mrb-item"><label><input type="radio" name="td_p1"  mrbvalue="Sometimes"> Sometimes</label></div>

    </div> 
 </td>
</tr>



$(".mrb-item").click(function() {
    var checkboxes = $(".mrb-item");

    for(var i =0; i < checkboxes.length; i++){

    if($('input').attr("mrbvalue")  == "Yes" ){
        console.log("yes");
        }
    }
    if($('input').attr("mrbvalue")  == "No" ){
        console.log("No");
        }
    }
    if($('input').attr("mrbvalue")  == "Sometimes" ){
        console.log("Sometimes");
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: When you use `$('input').attr("mrbvalue")  == "Yes"` You are basically always getting the first input. Regardless of the `for` loop, you need to use something like `eq`. I posted an answer to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify the code as below.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td> <span>P1</span> </td>
<td> <div class="n-mrb n-choice tbl" nfield="td_p1" value="1">
<div class="mrb-item"><label><input type="radio" name="td_p1"  mrbvalue="Yes"/> Yes</label></div>
<div class="mrb-item"><label><input type="radio" name="td_p1"  mrbvalue="No"/> No</label></div>
<div class="mrb-item"><label><input type="radio" name="td_p1"  mrbvalue="Sometimes"/> Sometimes</label></div>
</div> 
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $(".mrb-item input").click(function() {
        var mrbValue=$(this).attr("mrbvalue");
        if(mrbValue== "Yes" ){
            console.log("yes");
        }
        if(mrbValue== "No" ){
            console.log("No");
        }
        if(mrbValue== "Sometimes" ){
            console.log("Sometimes");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your if statement, every time you loop, you always get the first input. You need to use `eq`.

```
    // This is wrong
    if($('input').attr("mrbvalue")  == "No" ){
        console.log("No");
    }

    // This is right
    if($('input').eq(i).attr("mrbvalue")  == "No" ){
        console.log("No");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

- jQuery: $('input[name="td_p1"]:checked').attr('mrbvalue')
- pure javascript: document.querySelector('input[name="td_p1"]:checked').getAttribute('mrbvalue')